# "Global Undo" in User Preferences -> Editing Keeps unchecking itself

Tags: customization

"Global Undo" in User Preferences -> Editing Keeps unchecking itself.

As a result, I'm not able to use ctrl + z

I'm not sure when it happens - maybe after coming back to my computer after putting it to sleep the previous day.

When I re-enable it, it undoes (only God knows how many) previous steps. My models go back to "some other" stage they were in before.

Not good!

Any ideas?

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Did you try saving over your user preferences with it enabled?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Yes I tried that, still the same result.